# Bokeh RuntimeError: Models must be owned by only a single document, Selection(id='1057', ...) is already in a doc

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to plot several graphs in Bokeh, but I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Models must be owned by only a single document, Selection(id='1057', ...) is already in a doc.
```

I know that this is caused when trying to use the same objects in multiple docs, but I don't understand where I am doing that. Here is the entire (simplified) code.

I'm using Bokeh 1.4.0.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import output_file
import pandas as pd

feature_groups  = [['ciao'],['bye']]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x':[0,1,2,3,4], 'y':[2,3,4,5,6]})
x_test = [0,1,2,3,4]
y_test = [2,3,4,5,6]
source = ColumnDataSource(df)


for features_columns in feature_groups:
    output_file('features_labels' + features_columns[0] +'.html')
    p = []

    for k,f in enumerate(features_columns):
        p_k = figure(title=f)
        p_k.circle(x=f, y='ki', line_width=2, source=source,fill_alpha=0.5,line_alpha=0.5)
        p_k.circle_cross( x=x_test, y=y_test, color='red',fill_alpha=0.5,line_alpha=0.5)
        p_k.circle_cross( x = x_test, y = y_test, color='green',fill_alpha=0.5,line_alpha=0.5)
        p_k.xaxis.axis_label = f
        p_k.yaxis.axis_label = 'ki'
        p.append(p_k)
    grid = gridplot(p, ncols=2)
    show(grid)
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I just posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735710/bokeh-models-must-be-owned-by-only-a-single-document/67047128#67047128) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) like the error says each Bokeh model (in this case instance of `ColumnDataSource`) can be added to the Bokeh `Document` only once so just move `source = ColumnDataSource(df)` to the `for` loop.

EDIT (thanks to [bigreddot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406693/bigreddot)): Apparently you can share the same `source` only between glyphs and plots in the same Bokeh `Document` and not between different documents. Methods like `output_file`, `save` and `show` implicitly create a new Bokeh `Document` so using the same `source` in combination with two `output_file` statements in your original code will always cause a problem

2) you refer to fields that don't exist in your ColumnDataSource like 'ki' etc. I replaced them with `x='x'` and `y='y'`

See below corrected and working code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import output_file
import pandas as pd

feature_groups  = [['ciao'],['bye']]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x':[0,1,2,3,4], 'y':[2,3,4,5,6]})
x_test = [0,1,2,3,4]
y_test = [2,3,4,5,6]

for features_columns in feature_groups:
    output_file('features_labels' + features_columns[0] +'.html')
    p = []
    source = ColumnDataSource(df)

    for k,f in enumerate(features_columns):
        p_k = figure(title=f)
        p_k.circle(x='x', y='y', line_width=2, source=source,fill_alpha=0.5,line_alpha=0.5)
        p_k.circle_cross( x=x_test, y=y_test, color='red',fill_alpha=0.5,line_alpha=0.5)
        p_k.circle_cross( x = x_test, y = y_test, color='green',fill_alpha=0.5,line_alpha=0.5)
        p_k.xaxis.axis_label = f
        p_k.yaxis.axis_label = 'ki'
        p.append(p_k)
    grid = gridplot(p, ncols=2)
    show(grid)
```

Comment: You can share CDS objects on different plots, as long as they are the same `Document`. But `output_file`, `show` etc implicitly create new documents under the covers which why the original code triggers this condition.

Comment: @Tony Won't this create 2 separate HTMLs?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function show_bokeh(grid)

```
def show_bokeh(plot_fig):
    try:
        bpl.reset_output()
        bpl.output_notebook()
        bpl.show(plot_fig)
    except:
        bpl.output_notebook()
        bpl.show(plot_fig)
```

instead of show()